# Disable all checkboxes after 1 row is selected

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to disable the checkboxes for all rows except the one the user selects.  There can only be one selection made and they should be able to unselect one which would re-enable the other checkboxes again.  I have created a simple example as a starting point. I am new to Knockout and I am stuck.  Thanks for any help.

```js
var DuplicatesVM = (function() {

  var self = this;
  self.Duplicates = ko.observableArray();
  self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray([]);

});

var DuplicateVM = (function(data) {

  var self = this;

  //Map JS to Item
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

});

var rawData = {
  "@odata.context": "Data",
  "value": [{
    "dos_personId": "c1",
    "dos_lastname": "Smith",
    "dos_firstname": "Joe",
    "dos_name": "Smith, Joe   ",
  }, {
    "dos_personId": "c2",
    "dos_lastname": "Blow",
    "dos_firstname": "Joe",
    "dos_name": "Blow, Joe   ",
  }, {
    "dos_personId": "c3",
    "dos_lastname": "Davis",
    "dos_firstname": "Joe",
    "dos_name": "Davis, Joe   ",
  }]
};


$(document).ready(function() {
  var DupVM = new DuplicatesVM();
  $.each(rawData.value, function(k, l) {
    //alert(JSON.stringify(l));
    DupVM.Duplicates.push(new DuplicateVM(l));
  });
  ko.applyBindings(DupVM);
});


//* collapsible debug section script
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* Style the button that is used to open and close the collapsible content */

.collapsible {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}


/* Add a background color  if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the collapsible content. Note: hidden by default */

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Option</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: Duplicates">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.selectedItems"></intput>
    </td>
    <td data-bind="text: dos_personId"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: dos_name"></td>
  </tbody>

</table>
<div id="debug" style="clear: both">
  <h2 class="collapsible">Show Debug</h2>
  <div class="content" data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></div>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `enable` binding with a function to check the collection of checked items.

```
enable: $root.selectedItems().length===0 || $root.selectedItems().indexOf($data) >= 0
```

Example:

```js
var DuplicatesVM = (function() {
  var self = this;
  self.Duplicates = ko.observableArray();
  self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray([]);
});

var DuplicateVM = (function(data) {
  var self = this;
  //Map JS to Item
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
});

var rawData = { "@odata.context": "Data", "value": [{ "dos_personId": "c1", "dos_lastname": "Smith", "dos_firstname": "Joe", "dos_name": "Smith, Joe   ", }, { "dos_personId": "c2", "dos_lastname": "Blow", "dos_firstname": "Joe", "dos_name": "Blow, Joe   ", }, { "dos_personId": "c3", "dos_lastname": "Davis", "dos_firstname": "Joe", "dos_name": "Davis, Joe   ", }] }; 

$(document).ready(function() {
  var DupVM = new DuplicatesVM();
  $.each(rawData.value, function(k, l) {
    //alert(JSON.stringify(l));
    DupVM.Duplicates.push(new DuplicateVM(l));
  });
  ko.applyBindings(DupVM);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Option</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: Duplicates">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.selectedItems, enable: $root.selectedItems().length===0 || $root.selectedItems().indexOf($data) >= 0" />
    </td>
    <td data-bind="text: dos_personId"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: dos_name"></td>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I knew I was close but I was making it more complicated.  I have ALL the fiddles to prove it :-)

Comment: @ilgy That sounds familiar ;)